# updates to global object not reflecting by changing value of local object in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Today I faced a very strange issue in Objective C, if anybody can help me figure out, i would really appreciate it. Let me explain the scenario.

Below is the case:

1. I make a webservice call and get NSArray of Objects and cached in Global class.
2. I have a local NSArray in view controller which is nothing but assigned from Global class array. Like this

   ```
   self.listOfObjects = [GlobalCache sharedInstance].listOfObjects
   ```

   self.listOfObjects is **strong** and **nonatomic**.
3. In a scenario I updated an object in self.listofobjects, lets say nameProperty of the object in array. Its updated in self.listOfObjects and when i print object using command

   ```
   po ((ObjectType*)self.listOfObjects[0]).name
   ```

   its fine and printing the updated value.
4. But when i see the value in GlobalCache of the same objects, Its not reflecting ***sometimes*** its still having old values.
5. `self.listOfObjects` is just reference to the GlobalCache listOfobject. (No where it is copied from global cache to local object)

Could it be a memory problem?

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: Basically just a strong, copy, non atomic concept. Does setter method copies object and set it when we dont give "Copy".

Comment: If the local reference is the same as the global reference, then what is the point of the local reference?

Comment: Actually he is saving the response in global cache and just referring it from local controller. Have no idea why he did so, now am working on top of the code and facing this problem

Comment: What type of objects are inside the listOfObjects? Also is the array in the global scope mutable and whether the elements of this array mutable? Can you paste the Recipient model here? Are the name,email etc strong or copy properties? 

There is one possibility. May be the [GlobalCache sharedInstance].listOfObjects is getting rewritten after its assigned to the local property? Since you said  it happens sometimes and also that its set as a result of a web service call there is a chance that its being written again in a async manner via a network callback completion that you are not aware of.

Comment: Array is not mutable in both places. In local and global.

Comment: Have you tried clean build and reset simulator?

Comment: Nothing to do with cleaning and quitting xcode. The issue happening in device production build. Am able to reproduce this issue once in every ten times.

Comment: getter setter methods of global object may be overridden and gets the values from userDefaults or disc everytime, and because of this, everytime the global object is changed it needs to be syncronized.

Comment: @meth we are not saving it in userdefaults, its basically a class where i declared array.

Comment: Can you reliably reproduce this issue? That's your first task. If not, then inserting logging into the code is your second task. There are a number of things that could be going wrong here, most likely it is not a memory problem but rather something is not jiving with your assumptions about the code. When you notice the error is it the values that are different or the array pointers themselves?